# How to split a long list of email address using Python 3.2.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to split a long list of email address into lines, such as:

```
test01@testing.com; test02@testing.com; test03#testing1.com; test04@testing2.com,
```

I wish to split them into lines:

```
test01@testing.com (carriage return)
test02@testing.com (carriage return)
test03#testing1.com (carriage return)
test04@testing2.com
```

Can anyone pls help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to split by semi-colon and `strip` to remove any spaces:

```
>>> s = "test01@testing.com; test02@testing.com; test03#testing1.com"
>>> [(e.strip() + '\n') for e in s.split(';')]
['test01@testing.com\n', 'test02@testing.com\n', 'test03#testing1.com\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the addresses in multiple lines, [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove commas and semi-colons, and [`join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to rearrange them.

```
>>> s = 'test01@testing.com; test02@testing.com; test03#testing1.com; test04@testing2.com,'
>>> print('\n'.join(m.strip(',;') for m in s.split())))
test01@testing.com
test02@testing.com
test03#testing1.com
test04@testing2.com
```

Comment: Have a look at the links, the documentation explains lots of great functions. By the way, if this (or any other) answer solves your problem, feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (and potentially upvote) it. Thanks!

Comment: you have to be careful. ;, can be part of the local-part (everything before the @) of an email address. so a simple split is not bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

How about using regex:

```
import re
elist = re.findall(r'([^;,]+)', long_list)
print "".join("\n", elist)
```

Comment: Um, the regular expression doesn't consider the whitespaces and the comma. Also, there is a syntactic error - you're missing a `'`. Also, `str.join` only takes one argument aside from `self`. To top it off, print is not a statement in Python 3 anymore.

Comment: The white space is irrelevant. The poster wanted to capture the addresses. As for typo, that was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to maintain them as a single multiline string, a simple string substitution will do the trick:

```
long_list.replace('; ', '\n')
```

A more flexible solution could use regex:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\s+;\s+', '\n')
```